# How can you use @ symbols in classnames when using SASS?

Tags: sass

Is it possible to have an `@` symbol in a classname when using sass?
I keep getting compilation errors even though it seems to be valid syntax in CSS.

I want classnames like:

```
.u-6@sm {
    width: 50%;
}
```

I've tried a variaty of approaches using interpolation but can't get it to spit out the CSS with the `@` symbol.

e.g.

```
$at-symbol: unquote('@');
.u-6#{$at-symbol}sm {
    width: 50%;
}
```

That doens't work. I also tried a function to return it and a mixin that accepts a symbol as a param but still nothing.

The weirdest thing is that if I do this:

```
.u-6\@sm {
    width: 50%;
}
```

it compiles fine with both backslash and the `@` symbol. Huh? Whaa?  So why can't I use just the `@`?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with SASS. `@` is a character that needs escaping in CSS, probably because it's part of the language syntax (e.g. `@import`).

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález, you were right.  Someone tipped me in that direction just after I posted my question.  I actually didn't realise you could escape character in CSS!

Comment: I think a downvote is a bit harsh just because I didn't realise a sass compilation error was about escaping characters in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I just realised what's happening.
You can escape characters in CSS using the `\` which is why sass spits that out in it's entirity.  The CSS itself will then escape the `@` symbol.

Leaving the question up in case anyone finds it useful.